# Need help - ADD/Replace/Remove nodes in XML based on conditions using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform following two XMLs(Input XML # 1 and Input XML # 2) using XSLT. I would need your help to transform them using XSLT as I'm sturggling to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Input XML # 1

```
<Employee>
<Summary>
    <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
    <Name>Mel Gibson</Name>
</Summary>
<Personal>
    <First_Name>Mel</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Gibson</Last_Name>
</Personal>
<Status>
    <Active>Yes</Active>
    <Base_Location>Boston</Base_Location>
</Status>
<Summary_Information>
    <Location>California</Location>
    <Last_Formatted_Name>Samuel Gibson</Last_Formatted_Name>
</Summary_Information>
</Employee>
```

Condition to transform above XML is

If Last_Name node exists in the XML#1, that node should hold the value of Last_Formatted_Name after transformation and remove 
Last_Formatted_Name node from XML#1.

Output should look like as below. Please note Last_Name is holding the value of Last_Formatted_Name and Last_Formatted_Name is removed.

```
<Employee>
<Summary>
    <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
    <Name>Mel Gibson</Name>
</Summary>
<Personal>
    <First_Name>Mel</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Samuel Gibson</Last_Name>
</Personal>
<Status>
    <Active>Yes</Active>
    <Base_Location>Boston</Base_Location>
</Status>
<Summary_Information>
    <Location>California</Location>
</Summary_Information>
</Employee>
```

Input XML # 2

```
<Employee>
<Summary>
    <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
    <Name>Mel Gibson</Name>
</Summary>
<Personal>
    <First_Name>Mel</First_Name>
</Personal>
<Status>
    <Active>Yes</Active>
    <Base_Location>Boston</Base_Location>
</Status>
<Summary_Information>
    <Location>California</Location>
    <Last_Formatted_Name>Samuel Gibson</Last_Formatted_Name>
</Summary_Information>
</Employee>
```

Condition to transform XML# 2 is: If Last_Name does'nt exist in input XML, a node Last_Name should be created right after First_Name node and should hold the value of Last_Formatted_Name

Output should look like below. Please note Last_Name node is created right after First_Name and Last_Formatted_Name node is removed.

```
<Employee>
<Summary>
    <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
    <Name>Mel Gibson</Name>
</Summary>
<Personal>
    <First_Name>Mel</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Samuel Gibson</Last_Name>
</Personal>
<Status>
    <Active>Yes</Active>
    <Base_Location>Boston</Base_Location>
</Status>
<Summary_Information>
    <Location>California</Location>
</Summary_Information>
</Employee>
```

Following XSLT is what i have written to achieve this, but doesn't produce the output that i wanted.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#default">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Personal">

    <xsl:if test="exists(Last_Name)">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Last_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Last_Formatted_Name"/>
        </Last_Name>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Personal">
<xsl:if test="not(Last_Name)">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Last_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Last_Formatted_Name"/>
        </Last_Name>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please share your XSLT code. The XMLs shared do not have a `</Employee>` node and hence not well-formed. Also your requirement is not clear. Do you want to use both the XMLs as input to the XSLT at the same time or you are looking for a generic XSLT for handling both the XMLs separately to transform the inputs in the desired output?

Comment: Hi Aniket, thanks for looking into this.  I've written following

Comment: Hi Aniket, I've updated original question with XSLT that I'm trying. yes, I want to us both the XMLs as input to the XSLT at same time. One XSLT should handle both XMLs. Seems like </Employee> was missing because of a formatting issue when I posted the question in StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- modifies the value of <Last_Name> if it exists -->
    <xsl:template match="Last_Name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../Summary_Information/Last_Formatted_Name" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- if <Last_Name> does not exist, creates a last name with the appropriate value -->
    <xsl:template match="Personal[not(Last_Name)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <Last_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="../Summary_Information/Last_Formatted_Name" />
            </Last_Name>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- removes the node -->
    <xsl:template match="Last_Formatted_Name" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket, I'll try this now and let you know of results

Comment: Hi Aniket, I'm running some problems with my XML and XSLT. There could be more nodes present in my input XML under Personal node. So, with above XSLT, last_name always gets inserted as last tag under "personal" node. In stead of this, Last_Name tag should be inserted right after First_Name tag. Do you know how can i change my XSLT to get that to work?

Comment: I've posted a new question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146870/how-to-insert-an-xml-tag-after-a-particular-tag-using-xslt